# for every two record increment the sequence - odoo 10

Tags: odoo, sequence, odoo-9, odoo-10

How to increment the sequence in every two records

for ex :

```
     Record 1 : sequence : 1
     Record 2 : sequence : 1(the same number)
     Record 3 : sequence : 2
     Record 4 : sequence : 2(the same sequence)
```

What is the best condition that i can use it to achieve this result in odoo 10

Regards

Comment: Why you want to do like that ? Can you please tell me the reason ? because there might some other configuration which can be fit into your requirement.

Comment: i have two sequences in my form. one will do normally the incrementation and the second will do the increamentation every two records. and the result will be like this : 

                                    1 | 1 | 1 -

                                -   2 | 1 | 1 -

                                    - 3 | 2 | 2 -

They are just some referencies that can help me to organize my archiving room by following this matrice(algo)

Comment: do you have any idea how achieve this.
Thanks in avdance

Answer (score 2):

You would have to inherit the create method of said model. In that method you have to check what the current sequence is (it's in 'ir.sequence'). Once you have the current sequence you can do a search to see how many times the sequence is used. If less than 2, use that sequence. Else ask the sequence model to give you a new sequence and use that when you are creating the new record.

Comment: Please can you transform this on code odoo 10 because i'm still new odoo, i will very grateful. thanks